# Azure DevOps: Multiple repositories or multiple folders in one repository?

Tags: azure-devops

In a project I'm planning to have following items/projects:
.Net Server, Ionic App, Angular Website and a C# Admin tool.

At first I made a project, created one repository and folders; Server, App, Website and AdminTool in the root. But as I want to use pipelines and structure my code best possible way, I'm thinking it might have some advantages creating a repository for each project, in my project.

This way I will trigger exactly the pipeline of the project which needs to be build and it might be more module structured.
But I also see the disadvantage of having to push multiple times for the same feature - Each for each involved project (e.g. IonicApp and Server). This way it's not that clear what is made across projects for one feature, which could be seen in one push.

Which way to structure this would you recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, a Git repository on Azure Repos should be no larger than 10GB. This aims to ensure reliability and availability for all customers.

If you put too many projects into one repository, and these projects may also contain some large files, it may dramatically increase the time to checkout, branch, fetch, and clone your code. This could bring you a bad experience with Git. For more details, you can see "[**Git limits**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/limits?view=azure-devops)".

So, in your case, maybe you can consider using [**Submodules**](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

- Create a repository for the main project.
- Create a repository for each sub-project.
- Set the repositories of sub-projects as the submodules of the main project's repository.
- For the source codes of the features that are involved in multiple projects, you also can set up a specific repository for each feature, and then set the feature repositories as submodules of the involved project repositories.

With this way, you can set up the pipeline for each repository. And you also can using the "[**pipeline-completion triggers**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)" feature when you want the changes in the submodule repositories also can trigger the pipelines for the repositories that is using the submodules.

Answer (score 0):

A separate repository for each project is highly recommended and considered best practice.
With this you will have benefits, like;

- smaller sized repos,
- every project integration with CICD separately.

Because at the moment you will be updating single app project, so why to bother other running projects

Comment: Where is this recommended? Please provide a link if I can. I don't like the drawback of having to both push changes on the App repo and the Server repo on every feature, which has changes in both (A lot of them do) and not be able to see the whole feature changes in one branch.